# Wait method doesn't correctly wait for the element to be visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Why doesn't my wait method correctly wait for the element to be visible?

1. I'm running the builds continuously within Jenkins but every now and then the method fails: Element is not visible waiting for 10 seconds..
2. I have set the wait variable to 10 seconds
3. Does my method look correct to you?

   ```
   public boolean WaitUntilWebElementIsVisible(WebElement element) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).isDisplayed();
       System.out.println("WebElement is visible using locator: " + element.toString());
       return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("WebElement is NOT visible, using locator: " + element.toString() + " ,Exception: " + e.getMessage());
       Assert.fail("Method failed: WaitUntilWebElementIsVisible");
       //Assert.fail("WebElement is NOT visible, using locator: " + element.toString());
       return false;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: just use this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))

Comment: What kind of element is it failing on?  checkbox?  radio button?  What version of Selenium do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good. You can consider to increase the time out. 10 seconds is very minimal. Try with 30 or more seconds.

Comment: my only concern is with many methods and i have also implemented a retry method (x3 retries per method, the time could add up)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like following in a method:

```
boolean result = false;
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
                    .withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                    
                    .pollingEvery(pollingIntervalInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)            
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)                     
                    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);                    
            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {   
                @Override 
                public Boolean apply( WebDriver webDriver ) {
                    try {
                        return webDriver.findElements(locator).size() > 0 && webDriver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();                          
                    } catch ( Exception e ) {
                        System.out.println("Got Exception for locator " +locator+ " while waiting for it to display. Trying again...");                     
                        return false;
                    }   
                }
            });
            result = true;
```